# Background-image for QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

How to set background image for `QLineEdit`? The following style sheet doesn't work

```
QLineEdit {
  background-image:url(:/images/13.png);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
QLineEdit { 
   border: 1px solid #000000;   //image work with this line and didn't work with out))
   image: url(:/images/13.png);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've removed ":" from my question. However changing to "image:" doesn't help. I've managed to set background image for `QProgressBar` instance. Does it mean QLineEdit doesn't support this feature?

Comment: thanks, i'll check your update in a minute. Surprisingly adding `lineEdit->setFrame(false);` solved the problem too

Comment: hmmm setting a border property doesn't change anything but border itself, using "image" instead of "background-image" makes the image smaller then its actual size, and both keywords works only if "frame" property being set to false

Answer (score 1):

better solution is:

```
#fileFilter
{
    background: url(/Users/karelhladky/Pictures/Icons/famfamfam/icons/emoticon_grin.png);
        // there is no need add border property
}
```