# qt change QLineEdit shape

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlineedit

I'm trying to create a custom shape `QLineEdit` with `QWidget::setMask()`. I redefined `resizeEvent` for my sub class `lineEdit`.

```
void MyLineEdit::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *ev)
{
   QPixmap pixmap(":/new/prefix1/region.png");
   setFixedSize(ev->size());
   setMask(pixmap.mask());
   setStyleSheet("background-color : gray");
}
```

But the `QlineEdit` isn't showed. Btw, it was added to a `QGridlayout` and I checked that `pixmap.isNull() == false` and the size was normal.
Did I miss something? Why isn't it displayed?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#resizeEvent "No drawing need be (or should be) done inside this handler.". Try ::paintEvent()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to subclass anything. Just use [style sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14038720/1387438).

```
editor->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit  {\n"
                      "    background: url(:/new/prefix1/region.png);\n"
                      "}");
```

or [based on documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#qpushbutton-and-images):

```
editor->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit  {\n"
                      "    border-image: url(:/new/prefix1/region.png) 3 3 3 3;\n"
                      "}");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works but not 100% well. Please see my update.